# Why are the values given by pyserial from my Arduino Uno now stuck after adding code?

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I am trying to store light sensor data from an Arduino Uno in a .csv file. At first I've used pyserial to establish a connection, which did work using this code:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)

while 1:
    arduinoData = ser.readline().decode('ascii')
    print(arduinoData)
```

The light sensor is placed in a dark box, so you constantly get 1.00 lux as a value. However, if you turn on the light source in that box you get data fluctuating between 2400 and 2500 lux. So pretty much what you would expect. The serial plotter in the Arduino IDE gives the same values.

Afterwards, I went on to write code for getting the timestamp, storing the data in a .csv file and plotting a graph:

```
import serial, time, pandas as pd, plotly.express as px
from datetime import datetime

try:
    COM3 = serial.Serial('COM3', baudrate=9600, timeout=1)
    print("Zum speichern der Daten COM3 entfernen")
    dataFile = open('DataLog.csv', 'w')
    dataFile.write('Zeit,Wert\r')
    arduinoData = COM3.readline().decode('ascii')
except:
    print("Es besteht keine Verbindung zu COM3")
    quit()

while 1:
    try:
        currentTime = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
        arduinoData = COM3.readline().decode('ascii')

        dataFile.write(currentTime)
        dataFile.write(',')
        arduinoData = arduinoData.replace("\r\n", "")
        dataFile.write(arduinoData)
        dataFile.write('\r')

        print(arduinoData)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    except:
        dataFile.close()
        print("COM3 entfernt, Daten gespeichert")

        df = pd.read_csv('DataLog.csv')
        fig = px.line(df, x='Zeit', y='Wert', title='Messwerte')
        fig.show()

        quit()
```

I now tried to record some data, but now the value stays at 1.00 lux even if you turn on the light. It has no effect.
When you first turn on the light source, and then run the program you get the values fluctuating between 2400 and 2500 lux again. But, even weirder, when you turn off the light this also continues. Despite the light being turned off you still get the fluctuating values.

Since the Arduino seems to give the correct values for the Arduino IDE and the first python code, I guess it has to do something with my python program; but I don't know what's wrong. Any help would be much appreciated.